# Spring Security + Keylock Adapter + Gateway + Kubernetes - too many redirects

Tags: java, kubernetes, spring-security, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I can't figure out how to set up the infrastructure in such a way that everything works.

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class SpringWebSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) {

    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);

    http.csrf().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    http.logout()
            .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);
}
}
```

Config Keylock adapter

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: ${KEYCLOAK_AUTH_URL}
  realm: test-realm
  resource: test-admin-client
  use-resource-role-mappings: false
  credentials:
  secret: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

Spring Geteway

```
  cloud:
gateway:
  globalcors:
    corsConfigurations:
      '[/**]':
        allowedOrigins: "*"
        allowedMethods: "*"
        allowedHeaders: "*"
  routes:
    - id: test-admin-client
      uri: lb://test-admin-client
      predicates:
        - Path=/apps/test-admin-client/**
      filters:
        - TokenRelay=
        - RewritePath=/apps/test-admin-client(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
```

When visiting the gateway address (gateway.dev.test/app/test-admin-client), there was a redirect to http://10.244.130.77/sso/login (the local IP address of the k8s module).

I fix this by:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);

    KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = (KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint)authenticationEntryPoint();
    entryPoint.setLoginUri("http://gateway.dev.test/app/test-admin-client/sso/login");

    http.csrf().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
    http.logout()
            .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);
}
```

It worked, now I could see the keycloak-server authorization window, but the request contained an incorrect redirect_uri with the local IP of my service pod. Like This:

```
https://{keycloack-server-hostname}
  ?response_type=code
  &client_id=na-polke-admin-client
  &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F10.244.130.77%2Fsso%2Flogin
  &state=057fabd5-27a1-4e19-9b61-90712f8c8a1
  &login=true
  &scope=openid
```

I fixed it with override getReuest() method on KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter

```
@Component
public class KeycloackAuthenticationProcessingFilterPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

private void process(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {

    filter.setRequestAuthenticatorFactory(new SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticatorFactory() {

        @Override
        public RequestAuthenticator createRequestAuthenticator(HttpFacade facade, HttpServletRequest request, KeycloakDeployment deployment, AdapterTokenStore tokenStore, int sslRedirectPort) {

            return new SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticator(facade, request, deployment, tokenStore, sslRedirectPort) {

                @Override
                protected OAuthRequestAuthenticator createOAuthAuthenticator() {

                    return new OAuthRequestAuthenticator(this, facade, deployment, sslRedirectPort, tokenStore) {

                        @Override
                        protected String getRequestUrl() {

                            return "http://gateway.dev.test/app/test-admin-client/sso/login";
                        }
                    };
                }

            };
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {

    if (bean instanceof KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter) {
        log.info("Injecting Custom handler...");
        process(((KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter) bean));
    }
    return bean;
}
```

}

In the end, i manage to successfully pass authorization and I get a redirect to http://gateway.dev.test/app/test-admin-client/sso/login but then the redirects go into a loop referring to gateway/app/admin-client/sso/login

What could be the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Keycloak adapters for Spring are deprecated and incompatible with Boot 3 / Security 6. Plus spring-cloud-gateway is a reactive application and keycloak adapters where designed for servlets. Refer to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) (main README first and then BFF tutorial) to configure your gateway properly. Only then, will you get a chance to have it work in k8s (my BFF tutorial is [deployed to k8s](https://bff.demo.c4-soft.com/ui/)).